# Why fs.copyFile is not working in Nodejs terminal?

Tags: javascript, node.js, hyperterminal

[error screenshot along with code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5d6O.png)
I am trying to copy content from one file to another but the hyperterminal throws error. I have no idea. Could you help?

I have entered the syntax for copyFile but it is not working ?whether it is because of version or something else?

Comment: Please check out the [question asking guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) specifically, **DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.—copy or type the text into the question.**

Comment: You need to pass the callback or you can use the promise version: [See documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fscopyfilesrc-dest-mode-callback) `fs.copyFile(src, dest, callback)`

Comment: The `callback` argument to `fs.copyFile()` is not optional. See the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fscopyfilesrc-dest-mode-callback)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use fs.copyFileSync